# ERROR [api internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.18.3

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

```
docker-compose build
```

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I cannot solve this problem with docker, I tried to, and I changed docker engine

from:

```
{
  "builder": {
    "features": {
      "buildkit": true
    },
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
}
```